# displays highest sales figure and average sales

Tags: c++

l have this program in C++ to find highest sales figure and average but its giving errors below help please

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// You must add the three functions here

void getSales(float & sales1P, float & sales2P, float & sales3P,
        float & sales4P) {

    cout << "Enter four sales values: " << endl;

    cin >> sales1P >> sales2P >> sales3P >> sales4P;
}

float calcAverage(float sales1P, float sales2P, float sales3P, float sales4P) {

    return (sales1P + sales2P + sales3P + sales4P) / 4;
}

float findHighest(float sales1P, float sales2P, float sales3P, float sales4P)

{

    float highest = sales1P;
    if (sales2P > highest)
        highest = sales2P;
    if (sales3P > highest)
        highest = sales3P;
    if (sales4P > highest)
        highest = sales4P;
}

void displayOutput(float highestSales, float averageSales) {
    cout << "The highest sales figure is " << highestSales

    << " with an average of " << averageSales << endl;
}

int main()

{
    float sales1,
    sales2,
    sales3,
    sales4;
    float averageSales;
    float highestSales;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    // Get the sales for each division.
    sales1 = getSales();
    sales2 = getSales();
    sales3 = getSales();
    sales4 = getSales();
    //
    //getSales(sales1, sales2, sales3, sales4);
    averageSales = calcAverage(sales1, sales2, sales3, sales4);
    //getSales(sales1, sales2, sales3, sales4);
    highestSales = findHighest(sales1, sales2, sales3, sales4);
    displayOutput(highestSales, averageSales);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
error::::    In function `int main()': 
\Examples_C++\question_4a.cpp 5 C:\Examples_C++\C [Error] too few arguments to function void getSales(float&, float&, float&, float&)' 
\Examples_C++\question_4a.cpp 41 C:\Examples_C++\C [Error] at this point in file 
\Examples_C++\question_4a.cpp 41 C:\Examples_C++\C [Error] void value not ignored as it ought to be
\Examples_C++\question_4a.cpp 5 C:\Examples_C++\C [Error] too few arguments to function `void getSales(float&, float&, float&, float&)' 
\Examples_C++\question_4a.cpp 42 C:\Examples_C++\C [Error] at this point in file 
\Examples_C++\question_4a.cpp 42 C:\Examples_C++\C [Error] void value not ignored as it ought to be 
\Examples_C++\question_4a.cpp 5 C:\Examples_C++\C [Error] too few arguments to function `void getSales(float&, float&, float&, float&)' 
\Examples_C++\question_4a.cpp 43 C:\Examples_C++\C [Error] at this point in file 
\Examples_C++\question_4a.cpp 43 C:\Examples_C++\C [Error] void value not ignored as it ought to be 
\Examples_C++\question_4a.cpp 5 C:\Examples_C++\C [Error] too few arguments to function `void getSales(float&, float&, float&, float&)' 
\Examples_C++\question_4a.cpp 44 C:\Examples_C++\C [Error] at this point in file 
\Examples_C++\question_4a.cpp 44 C:\Examples_C++\C [Error] void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged any of the other languages

Comment: The errors are pretty self explanatory.  What don't you understand about them?

Answer (score 2):

At this section:

```
sales1 = getSales();

sales2 = getSales();

sales3 = getSales();

sales4 = getSales();
```

you're using a function called (getSales) that ought to have this signature: getSales(float&, float&, float&, float&). This means that the function takes 4 arguments, and you're giving it 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is your function definition:

```
void getSales(float & sales1P, float & sales2P, float & sales3P, float & sales4P)
```

This is how you are calling it:

```
sales1 = getSales();

sales2 = getSales();

sales3 = getSales();

sales4 = getSales();
```

Do you see the disconnect between the definition and how it's being called?

You need to call getSales() with 4 Float Addresses

EDIT: Since OP seems to be having issues compreheding it...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// You must add the three functions here
//changed these to take pointers to floats
void getSales(float *sales1P, float *sales2P, float *sales3P, float *sales4P) {

cout << "Enter four sales values: " <
//Changed the cin to store in the content of pointers
cin >> *sales1P >> *sales2P >> *sales3P >> *sales4P; }

float calcAverage(float sales1P, float sales2P, float sales3P, float sales4P) {

return (sales1P + sales2P + sales3P + sales4P) / 4; }

float findHighest( float sales1P, float sales2P, float sales3P, float sales4P)

{

float highest = sales1P;
if (sales2P > highest)
    highest = sales2P;
if (sales3P > highest)
    highest = sales3P;
if (sales4P > highest)
    highest = sales4P;
//You were for some reason missing the return statement on highest here. 
return highest;
}

void displayOutput(float highestSales, float averageSales) { cout << "The highest sales         figure is " << highestSales  << " with an average of " << averageSales <<endl;
}

int main()

{

float sales1,sales2,sales3,sales4;

float averageSales;

float highestSales;

//for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)

// Get the sales for each division.
//The For loop here is useless. Call the function with the addresses of the float values. 
getSales(&sales1, &sales2, &sales3, &sales4);


averageSales = calcAverage(sales1, sales2, sales3, sales4);



highestSales = findHighest(sales1, sales2, sales3, sales4);

displayOutput(highestSales, averageSales);

system("PAUSE");

return 0;

}
```

It would be useful for you to read up on [pointers](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/).

1. The for loop here is useless
2. I changed the definition to accept pointers to floats
3. I passed in the float addresses as parameters
4. You missed a return statement in your getHighest() function.
5. Also, you were assigning something to the result of getSales, but getSales returns **void**.

I recommend you go back and learn the basics of functions and assignment.

Have a good day!

Comment: thanks...the question is how can l call those functions any example will help

Answer (score 0):

```
// getSales(sales1, sales2, sales3, sales4);
```

That's correct. Why did you comment it out and go directly against the parameter count of the function you defined?

Also, your `for` loop is probably not doing what you think it's doing. You forgot the `{}`. What you have now will execute *only* the first line 4 times.

Comment: thanks for that ..... how can l overcome error